# How to remove a block of known lines (an entire function) from a script using bash...?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, text-parsing

How would you remove a known part of a file, for example the one below:

```
func1() {
  # some code with conditions
  if [...]; then...
  # with some new lines too

  # some code again
}
```

from a script file?

I tried this way:

```
grep -xvF "$(cat <<'HEREDOC'
func1() {
  # some code with conditions
  if [...]; then...
  # with some new lines too

  # some code again
}
HEREDOC
)" file > ouput
```

It works, except that it removes any new line. I haven't found a way of sorting this out.
I made an attempt with awk but it was throwing syntax errors on the brackets and `=` signs found in the block.
The examples I found on StackExchange platforms generally try to remove several lines by pattern.
Does someone have a way of achieving this being able to deal with the special characters and keeping the output file similar to what it was before?

Comment: You may want to try `sed '/^func1() {$/,/^}$/d' file >output`

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin, your solution works. My only problem is that I include this text-parsing feature in a library. The block of code to be removed is passed as a parameter, and could be anything, a function or a single line.
I also want to enforce what is being removed. So that if the content of the function is not identical to what it was initially, it means the functions has been customised and then I don't touch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z -f <(sed 's|[.*^$/\[]|\\&|g; s|$|\\n|; 1s|^|s/|; $a //g' delete.txt | tr -d '\n') file
```

The `delete.txt` contains the contiguous portion that is to be removed from the `file`